# Как сделать такой hover эффект при наведении на изображение?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребята как сделать такой hover эффект при наведение мыши?

Я реализовал данный эффект через JS все работает, но мне кажется это не правильно. Я думаю, код не должен быть таким громоздким.

Есть еще другие способы на чистом JS? где бы код так много не повторялся.

[image: hover эффект]

```
  let projectLatest = document.querySelectorAll('.latest-project img'),
    projectInfo = document.querySelectorAll('.project-info'),
    hoverLink = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-link'),
    zoomIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-search');

for (let i = 0; i < projectLatest.length; i++) {
    projectLatest[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        projectLatest[i].style.transition = '0.5s';
        projectLatest[i].style.opacity = '0.5';
        projectInfo[i].style.background = '#362f2d';
        hoverLink[i].style.display = 'block';
        zoomIcon[i].style.display = 'block';
    });

    projectLatest[i].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        projectLatest[i].style.transition = '0.5s';
        projectLatest[i].style.opacity = '1';
        projectInfo[i].style.background = '#fbfaf8';
        hoverLink[i].style.display = 'none';
        zoomIcon[i].style.display = 'none';
    });
}

for (let i = 0; i < projectInfo.length; i++) {
    projectInfo[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        projectInfo[i].style.transition = '0.5s';
        projectInfo[i].style.background = '#362f2d';
        projectLatest[i].style.opacity = '0.5';
        hoverLink[i].style.display = 'block';
        zoomIcon[i].style.display = 'block';
    });

    projectInfo[i].addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        projectInfo[i].style.transition = '0.5s';
        projectInfo[i].style.background = '#fbfaf8';
        projectLatest[i].style.opacity = '1';
        hoverLink[i].style.display = 'none';
        zoomIcon[i].style.display = 'none';
    });
}

for (let i = 0; i < hoverLink.length; i++) {
    hoverLink[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        projectInfo[i].style.transition = '0.5s';
        projectInfo[i].style.background = '#362f2d';
        projectLatest[i].style.opacity = '0.5';
        hoverLink[i].style.display = 'block';
        zoomIcon[i].style.display = 'block';
    });
}

for (let i = 0; i < zoomIcon.length; i++) {
    zoomIcon[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        projectInfo[i].style.transition = '0.5s';
        projectInfo[i].style.background = '#362f2d';
        projectLatest[i].style.opacity = '0.5';
        hoverLink[i].style.display = 'block';
        zoomIcon[i].style.display = 'block';
    });
```

Comment: Единственное, что делает ваш js - работает со стилями (`projectLatest[i].style`).. Собственно, вопрос - зачем js? У вас всё написанное касается стилей, вот и используйте css3 для этого. Нет смысла юзать js там, где можно обойтись без него.

Comment: Если покажете вашу html разметку и css, то можно сделать на чистом css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.block {
  background-color: #fbfaf8;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

.block .image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block .image .actions {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(56, 46, 45, 0.7);
  transition: visibility .5s, transform .5s;
}

.block .image .actions a {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #bcb3a2;
  transition: color .2s;
}

.block .image .actions a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.block .description {
  padding: 26px 15px;
  color: #a79a8a;
}

.block .description h4 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.block .description p {
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: color .5s;
}

.block:hover {
  background-color: #382e2d;
}

.block:hover .image .actions {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: visibility 0s, transform .5s;
}

.block:hover .description p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 px-1 mb-3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          <h4>Claritas Etiam Processus</h4>
          <p>Photography, Nature</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 px-1 mb-3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          <h4>Claritas Etiam Processus</h4>
          <p>Photography, Nature</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 px-1 mb-3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          <h4>Claritas Etiam Processus</h4>
          <p>Photography, Nature</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 px-1 mb-3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          <h4>Claritas Etiam Processus</h4>
          <p>Photography, Nature</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 px-1 mb-3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          <h4>Claritas Etiam Processus</h4>
          <p>Photography, Nature</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 px-1 mb-3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          <h4>Claritas Etiam Processus</h4>
          <p>Photography, Nature</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Добавлю свой сниппет того, что это делается на CSS, как в принципе и нужно делать.
Для таких задач нужно пихать то, что для этого предназначено.

Использовал Bootstrap и FontAwesome для сетки и иконок соотвественно.

Анимации накидал самые простые что есть, доводить до уж красоты не стал, чисто чтобы показать как это делается на CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно (и нужно) делать на чистом CSS. В CSS есть псевдо-класс `:hover`,  который применяется к тем элементам, на которых находится указатель мыши.

Обратите внимание на то что мы можем указать `:hover` только для родительского элемента, а элементам внутри мы не делаем `:hover` (мы делаем `.link:hover .img`, но не `.link .img:hover`.

Еще стоит обратить внимание на то что `:hover` желательно применять к элементам, которые реагируют на клик мыши. Таким как ссылка или кнопка. В противном случае может получиться убого и непрофессионально: элемент меняет цвет, но на щелчёк не реагирует. Как говорится, гугл так не делает.

```css
/* Стили по умолчанию */
.link {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.link .img {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid Gray;
}

.link .text {
  color: Green;
  display: block;
}

/* Стили при наведении */
.link:hover {
  background-color: Blue;
}

.link:hover .img {
  border-color: Red;
}

.link:hover .text {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="/link" class="link">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img" />
  <span class="text">Click me!</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите уменьшить размер кода js для вставки стиля  можно вставлять по несколько стилей сразу, использовав свой скрипт наподобие такого или можно использовать jquery css или http://zamjs.com/
Пример подобного подхода:

```
   var setStyle = function(p_elem, p_styles)
   {
       var s;
       for (s in p_styles)
       {
           p_elem.style[s] = p_styles[s];
       }
   }

   let projectLatest = document.querySelectorAll('.latest-project img'),
   projectInfo = document.querySelectorAll('.project-info'),
   hoverLink = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-link'),
   zoomIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-search');

   for (let i = 0; i < projectLatest.length; i++) {
   setStyle(projectLatest[i], {'transition': '0.5s', 'opacity': '0.5'});
   setStyle(projectInfo[i], {'background': '#362f2d'});
   setStyle(hoverLink[i], {'display': 'block'});
   setStyle(zoomIcon[i], {'display': 'block'});
   }
```