# Ховер на блок показать две иконки?

Tags: css, css3, html5

Как примерно делать такой ховер тот что справа
Именно интересует о двух иконках
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Точная копия вопроса отсюда - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036819/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-hover-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/1037122#1037122

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать такой hover эффект при наведении на изображение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036819/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-hover-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: нету дубликата 
я воот что накидал (просто сам подумал)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
  .icon {display: none;}
  .wrapper {
   width: 300px;
   height: 270px;
   background-color: orange;

  }
  h1 {
   margin: 10px;
  }
  .wrapper:hover {
   background-color: #999;
  }
  .wrapper:hover .icon {
   display: block;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div class="icon">1</div>
  <div class="icon">2</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>